# What HTML processing is used on observablehq?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, markup, observablehq

I just read up on [the changes in d6.js version 6](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-6-0) and stumbled across [this d3.groups() example on observablehq.com](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group).

There, I saw the following code snippet to create an HTML table from the `Map` `athletesBySport`:

```
html`<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Sport</th><th>Athletes</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>${Array.from(athletesBySport, ([key, values]) => html`
    <tr>
      <td>${key}</td>
      <td>${values.map(d => d.name).join(", ")}</td>
    </tr>`)}</tbody>
</table>`
```

What kind of "markup" / HTML processing is this? Some special patterns that I can detect are

```
hmtl`...`
```

and the

```
$
```

sign which seems to allow to execute a script that generates inline html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found [here, in Observable's standard library](https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib/blob/master/README.md#html). [This introduction](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/standard-library?collection=@observablehq/notebook-fundamentals) also explores the standard library.

---

The

```
html`...`
```

part is "just" a [JavaScript *tagged template literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates), i.e., a JavaScript template literal that is parsed with a specific method.

From Observable's documentation:

> html`string`
>
> Returns the HTML element represented by the specified HTML string literal. This function is intended to be used as a tagged template literal. Leading and trailing whitespace is automatically trimmed. For example, to create an H1 element whose content is “Hello, world!”:
> html`<h1>Hello, world!`

---

The documentation further states how expressions embedded with `$` are handled:

> If an embedded expression is a DOM element, it is embedded in generated HTML. For example, to embed TeX within HTML:
>
> html`I like ${tex`\KaTeX`} for math.`

> If an embedded expression is an array, the elements of the array are embedded in the generated HTML.

---

There are more tagged literals availabe in Observable, such as [`svg`](https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib#svg), [`md`](https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib#md) for markdown, [`tex`](https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib#tex) for LaTex, and more.